# Confused about circuit analysis example

Tags: circuit-analysis

This is probably going to seem like a dumb question but how would you calculate the current i1 in this example?

[image: circuit]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a homework question without showing any prior effort whatsoever.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: It's not a homework question. I was confused about why the 6V source was irrelevant (I already know the answer). Maybe I should have included this part in my OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the 12V voltage source is supposed to be an ideal voltage source it *forces* 12V across the 4m resistor. It doesn't matter what the 6V source and its resistors do. The voltage across the resistor is 12V and therefore the current through it is fixed by Ohm's law I=V/R.

Any eventual currents caused by the 6V source will be taken into account by I3.